# Why does branch B have conflicts in all merge commits from A to B after the first merge commit?

Tags: git, git-merge, shared, git-branch-sculpting, git-history

I have a primary development branch (A) which has a long history. All release commits in A are tagged as such. I checked out the root commit of A, and branched into test (B).

So I have a primary branch A, and the head of branch B pointing at the root commit of A. My goal is to create a history of all releases by merging each tagged commit from A to B.

The first merge from A into B works as expected, no conflicts.

```
$git checkout B
$git merge [release-commit-ID] --squash
$git commit -m "release#"
```

The first commit works great, but all other commits treat all merge commits as complete conflicts. I see that the root of B is the same as the root of A, but no shared history is recognized after the first squashed merge commit from the first release commit in A into B. What is causing the conflicts and how do I get shared history to be recognized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is causing the conflicts and how do I get shared history to be recognized?

There is no shared history (or rather, not enough).  There's nothing to recognize, which is why there are conflicts.

The key is the `--squash` flag:

> ```
> $ git checkout B
> $ git merge [release-commit-ID] --squash
> ```

The first step attaches your `HEAD` to the branch name `B`, checking out whichever commit the name `B` identifies:

```
...--*--C--D--E   <-- B (HEAD)
      \
       F--G--H   <-- somebranch
```

Here the name `B` identifies commit `E` (each of these letters stands in for the real hash IDs).  Commit `*` (which I would have named `B`, but you used that name for your branch) is the point at which the two development streams diverge, which means that when we work backwards (as Git does) it's the point where they come together.  You now run `git merge --squash <hash>` where `<hash>` identifies commit `F`, or `G`, or `H`, so Git compares the contents of commit `*` to the contents of commit `E` to find out what you changed:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> <hash-of-E>   # what we changed
```

and repeats with, say, `G`:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> <hash-of-G>   # what they changed
```

Git now combines these two sets of changes, applies the combined changes to commit `*`'s contents, and makes a new commit.

If you *don't* use `--squash`, Git records the new commit with *two* parents:

```
...--*--C--D--E--I   <-- B (HEAD)
      \         /
       F-------G--H   <-- somebranch
```

and now the most recent common starting point between the two lines is commit `G`.  But if you *do* use `--squash`, Git records the new commit with just *one* parent:

```
...--*--C--D--E--I   <-- B (HEAD)
      \
       F--G--H   <-- somebranch
```

and now the common starting point is unchanged.  All the work through `G` is in commit `I`, but commit `I` doesn't *remember* **why** that work is there.  A future `git merge` from commit `H` has to start over at commit `*`.

Git won't stop you from developing on branch `somebranch`, but in general, after a `git merge --squash`, you should consider the branch you merged *from* to be "dead" and just stop using it at all.  Once we've merged `G` with `git merge --squash` we should stop using `F` and `G` entirely.  This means we must also stop using `H` entirely.  If `H` is useful, we should copy it to a new, different commit:

```
$ git checkout -b newbranch B
```

giving us:

```
...--*--C--D--E--I   <-- B, newbranch (HEAD)
      \         /
       F-------G--H   <-- somebranch
```

followed by:

```
$ git cherry-pick somebranch   # or <hash of H>
```

to copy `H` to a very similar, but not identical, commit `H'`:

```
                   H'   <-- newbranch (HEAD)
                  /
...--*--C--D--E--I   <-- B
      \         /
       F-------G--H   <-- somebranch
```

We can now discard `somebranch`:

```
$ git branch -D somebranch
```

and rename `newbranch` to `somebranch` if we like.

(Note that we can do this copy-with-name-moving thing in one step using `git rebase --onto`, with `git checkout somebranch; git rebase --onto B <hash of G>`.  No matter how you do it, though, be aware that `git cherry-pick` cannot copy merge commits, and *anyone* who is using the commits we want to kill off—here the `F-G-H` chain—must do this killing-off-with-copying-the-ones-to-save thing.  So before using `--squash`, be sure you understand all the implications.)

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked that squashes will only have one parent, then all commits after said squash will conflict with all other previous squashes. This helped a lot.